# Remove the item which is selected in other ComboBox from source?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Suppose we have four ComboBoxes in view ([source](https://gist.github.com/JerryBian/7804536)):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection1}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected1}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection2}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected2}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection3}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected3}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection4}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected4}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the VM something like ([source](https://gist.github.com/JerryBian/7804542)):

```
public ObservableCollection<People> SourceCollection1 { get; set; }
...

private People _selected1;
public People Selected1
{
    get
    {
        return _selected1;
    }

    set
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
        {
            _selected1 = value;
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected1"));
        }
    }
}
...
```

And the `People` class has two properties: `Name` and `Age`.

So, I'd like to implement this feature: when user selected one item in `ComboBox1`, then the remaining ConboBoxes should adapt their own ItemsSource, removing the items which have been selected in other ComboBoxes.

For example, the application start up, and no item has been selected yet. Then user select `people A` in `ComboBox1`, so when user opens `ComboBox2` dropdown list, the `people A` item shouldn't be include in the `ComboBox2` source. So when user select p`eople B` in `ComboBox2`, the `ComboBox3` shouldn't have `people A` and `people B`. And so on...

Does anyone have some nice solutions?

Comment: you could use 4 ICollectionViews and filter the 3 other selected items from each source collection

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
public People Selected1
{
    get
    {
        return _selected1;
    }

    set
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        UpdateList (SourceCollection2, _selected, value);
        if (pc != null)
        {
            _selected1 = value;
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected1"));
        }

    }
}

private void UpdateList(ObservableCollection<People> list, People oldItem, People newItem){
    if(!list.Contains(oldItem)){
        list.Add(oldItem);
    }
    if(list.Contains(newItem)){
        list.Remove(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, you'd have to use the method once for each collection